# What does EAGAIN mean?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, posix

As in the title what does EAGAIN mean?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

[EAGAIN](https://web.archive.org/web/20130508062559/http://www.wlug.org.nz/EAGAIN) is often raised when performing [non-blocking I/O](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html). It means *"there is no data available right now, try again later"*.

It [might](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/errno.h.html) (or [might not](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/200004.mbox/%3CE12edKw-0002M2-00@fanf.eng.demon.net%3E)) be the same as `EWOULDBLOCK`, which means *"your thread would have to block in order to do that"*.

Comment: According to IEEE 1003.1, `EAGAIN` may be the same as `EWOULDBLOCK`. http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/errno.h.html

Comment: What I mean is: a portable program should not rely on them being distinct.

Comment: On Linux EAGAIN & EWOULDBLOCK are the same value but truly portable code should check both.

Comment: It might be because you reached a ulimit soft/hard resource such as threads, files or network connections.

Answer (score 29):

Using `man 2 intro | less -Ip EAGAIN`:

```
     35 EAGAIN Resource temporarily unavailable.  This is a temporary condi-
         tion and later calls to the same routine may complete normally.
```

Comment: Down to the core..  like it ;)

Answer (score 7):

What it means is less important. What it implies:

- your system call failed
- nothing happened (system calls are atomic, and this one just did not happen)
- you *could* try it again (it could fail *again*, possibly with a different result)
- or you *could* choose otherwise.

The whole thing about `EAGAIN` is that your process is not blocked inside the system call; it has the right to choose: either retry or do something useful.

Comment: Do you have a source to support the "system calls are atomic" claim? I find contradictory results

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt [errno(3) - Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html):

> EAGAIN Resource temporarily unavailable (may be the same value as EWOULDBLOCK) (POSIX.1-2001).

Use case: When epoll in ET mode, only wait after read or write return EAGAIN

Answer (score -1):

According to [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/apis/unix14.htm), it means "Operation would have caused the process to be suspended."

Comment: link gives HTTP 404