# EAGAIN EWOULDBLOCK Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth

I have developed an Android application that has multiple devices sending data back to a server device via Bluetooth socket connections, however am experiencing the error:

```
E/bt-btif: send none, EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK, errno:11
```

I have read that these errors occur on socket connections where the receiving device's socket buffer is full, however I am not sure how to handle it in an Android application..Is there a way that I can check for these errors before attempting transmission, or if they occur catch them and retry transmission later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get `EAGAIN`, simply retry the same operation again.

If you get `EWOULDBLOCK`, you must be using a non-blocking socket, and the requested operation would have caused the socket to block the calling thread.  Use `select()` to wait for the blocking condition to clear, then retry the original operation again.

Comment: EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK are different names for the same `errno.` Only your second paragraph applies.

Comment: EAGAIN is not always the same as EWOULDBLOCK on all platforms, that is why I separated them. [What does EAGAIN mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058368/)

Comment: Was interesting to learn about, I got it working by using a BufferedOutputStream for socket communication instead to ensure there was a buffer for bytes that could not be transmitted at that time to be retried later.

Comment: It's the same. You must call `select()` if you get either `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK.` If you recommend an alternative strategy for `EAGAIN` that doesn't involve `select()` you need to provide a citation for that. Another SO answer isn't a normative reference.