# AWS Aurora Serverless spewing 2 particular errors continuously

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-serverless, amazon-aurora

Looking in CloudWatch logs, I see these errors repeated continuously, approximately twice a second:

```
2019-03-10 00:56:12 2b1be9674700[AWS_OSCAR_ERROR]:Failed to read persisted replica status info. Error code = 11
2019-03-10 00:56:12 2b1be9674700[AWS_OSCAR_ERROR]:Failed to update replication status table (stage 2)
```

Does anyone know what these are? I've tried Googling the exact and partial errors and was amazed to see that there's nothing out there (well Google, anyway, has never seen them!)

I am concerned because --even if they are nothing to worry about-- they are generating millions of log entries and thus costing me lots in AWS fees.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linux error 11 is [`EAGAIN` -- not necessarily serious](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4058368/1695906) -- but that still doesn't look good.  You might want to post this question on the [official Aurora forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=227) where an Amazonian might see it, PM you for more details, and investigate.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an aurora internal error message (that explains why google didn't have much to offer when you searched for it). I think the right way ahead is to contact AWS Support.

Comment: Sensible advice, thanks, but I don't have the budget at this time to sign up for AWS support. It is a catch-22.

Comment: Well then I would recommend posting in AWS Forums with details of your cluster so that they can take a closer look.